# Ubuntu 14 Raid not booting

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, mdadm

i'm having issues for booting my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. I have two discs 320GB. I upgraded the disks from two 160GB and everything was working ok. Those disks were one IDE and the other SATA.
Now both disks are SATA.

Im seeing strange behaviours, to beginin with the raid doesnt have a UUID! this is my blkid:

/dev/sda1: UUID="b274a76e-7103-8037-fdd8-42b1bbea7745" UUID_SUB="e253af47-5b4d-5b52-ba86-87fcd317be88" LABEL="zabbix:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b274a76e-7103-8037-fdd8-42b1bbea7745" UUID_SUB="ca36f15c-6e79-eb1b-5eb4-e09752eb32f0" LABEL="zabbix:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
**/dev/md0: TYPE="nvidia_raid_member"**

I can access the data without problems, and the raid reports ok (now in resync):

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2] sda1[3]
      312505656 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [===>.................]  resync = 19.5% (60945344/312505656) finish=710.8min speed=5897K/sec

I already installed grub on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb
I already reconfigured the package grub-pc

If i use systemrescue dvd i can log to the system and work on it, but i dont know what else to do.

When i boot the system i get this error:

mount: mounting /dev/md0 on /root failed: No such device
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

And then busybox, initramfs prompt.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your raid array appears to be a disk in a fake raid, which is not even possible.  You must have left over fake raid signatures somehow.  Erase it with `sudo dmraid -E /dev/md0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Because i was in a hurry, i started over. Now i have a fully raid working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

(mdadm solution only; not clear from your question if you ended up using hardware or software RAID)

I'm not sure, but your description matches a problem I had during testing of my (software) RAID1 array - once I disconnected one of my disks to test that the RAID1 would survive a disc failure, I ended up in busybox. And without keyboard for good measure... The solution was to throw in a sleep script in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/sleepAwhile`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "sleeping for 30 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "sleeping for 25 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "sleeping for 20 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "sleeping for 15 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "sleeping for 10 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "sleeping for 5 seconds while udevd and mdadm settle down"
sleep 5
echo "done sleeping"
```

Next, make the script executable and install it.

```
chmod a+x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/sleepAwhile
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

Have you tested (cold-)unplugging a disk from your system to verify that your RAID device will continue to work?